# R and PostgreSQL - pre-specify possible column names and types

Tags: r, postgresql, odbc, google-cloud-sql

I have multiple large similar data files stored in `.csv` format. These are data files released annually. Most of these have the same variables but in some years they have added variables or changed the names of variables.

I am looping through my directory of files (~30 `.csv` files), converting them to data frames, and importing them to a Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL 12 database via:

```
DBI::dbAppendTable(con, tablename, df)
```

where `con` is my connection to the database, `tablename` is the table name, and `df` is the data frame produced from a `.csv`.

The problem is each of these `.csv` files will have a different number of columns and some won't have columns others have.

Is there an easy way to pre-define a structure to the PostgreSQL 12 database that specifies "any of these `.csv` columns will all go into this one database column" and also "any columns not included in the `.csv` should be filled with NA in the database". I think I could come up with something in R to make all the dataframes look similar prior to uploading to the database but it seems cumbersome. I am imaging a document like a JSON that the SQL database compares against kind of like below:

```
SQL | Data frame
----------------------------------
age = "age","Age","AGE"
sex = "Sex","sex","Gender","gender"
...
fnstatus = "funcstatus","FNstatus"
```

This would specify to the database all the possible columns it might see and how to parse those. And for columns it doesn't see in a given `.csv`, it would fill all records with `NA`.

Comment: How hard is it to define a super-set of possible column names? You can define the "not in every csv" columns as `NULL`, meaning when you insert those frames, the empty column is acceptable.

Comment: BTW: to find all names, if you have a list of filenames, then `table(unlist(lapply(filelist, read.csv, nrows=1)))` will tell you all names, and indicate which names are in all and which are not (based on the relative counts).

Comment: You mean define the superset in R? And thanks, that second comment is very helpful!

Comment: Yes. In other words, can you know a priori the possible columns names? Or do you open a CSV one day and realize that you have a new column?

Comment: I can know them a priori. Thats why I was saying I could probably do this with a script on the R side but I didn't know if there was an easier way on the SQL side like just defining a framework of all possible columns and all possible variations on those column names.

Comment: SQL generally does better defining all tables up front. It's certainly feasible with most DBMSes to `ALTER TABLE` and add columns, but sometimes that messes with optimal layout, etc. I'd say use my code above to find all possible columns, define them up-front, and allow the possibly-missing ones to be `NULL`.

Comment: Do you definite them upfront in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot say if such a feature is available as Postgres has many novel methods and extended data types, I would be hesitant to utilize such features as maintainability can be a challenge.

Enterprise, server, relational databases like PostgreSQL should be planned infrastructure systems. As r2evans comments, tables [including schemas, columns, users, etc.] should be defined up front. Designers need to think out entire uses and needs *before* any data migration or interaction. Dynamically adjusting database tables and columns by one-off application needs are usually not recommended. So clients like R should dynamically align data to meet the planned, relational database specifications.

One approach can be to use a temporary table as staging of all raw CSV data, possibly set with all `VARCHAR`. Then populate this table with all raw data to be finally migrated in a single append query using `COALESCE` and `::` for type casting to final destination.

```
# BUILD LIST OF DFs FROM ALL CSVs
df_list <- lapply(list_of_csvs, read.csv)

# NORMALIZE ALL COLUMN NAMES TO LOWER CASE
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(df), setNames(df, tolower(names(df))))

# RETURN LIST OF UNIQUE NAMES
all_names <- unique(lapply(df_list, names))

# CREATE TABLE QUERY
dbSendQuery(con, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTempTable")
sql <- paste("CREATE TABLE myTempTable (", 
             paste(all_names, collapse = " VARCHAR(100), "),
             "VARCHAR(100)",
             ")")
dbSendQuery(con, sql)

# APPEND DATAFRAMES TO TEMP TABLE
lapply(df_list, function(df) DBI::dbAppendTable(con, "myTempTable", df))

# RUN FINAL CLEANED APPEND QUERY
sql <- "INSERT INTO myFinalTable (age, sex, fnstatus, ...)
        SELECT COALESCE(age)::int
               , COALESCE(sex, gender)::varchar(5)
               , COALESCE(funcstatus, fnstatus)::varchar(10)
               ...
        FROM myTempTable"

dbSendQuery(con, sql)
```